# How do I respond to a POST request sent by Volley from a phone and add the contents into an SQL server?

Tags: php, android, networking

I'm building an app where to user sends some data via a POST request to a php server and it takes the data and adds it into an SQL server, but I'm getting a TimeoutError from Volley. Anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

To handle Android Volley Timeout you need to use RetryPolicy
RetryPolicy

```
Volley provides an easy way to implement your RetryPolicy for your requests.
Volley sets default Socket & ConnectionTImeout to 5 secs for all requests.
```

RetryPolicy is an interface where you need to implement your logic of how you want to retry a particular request when a timeout happens.

It deals with these three parameters

```
Timeout - Specifies Socket Timeout in millis per every retry attempt.
Number Of Retries - Number of times retry is attempted.
Back Off Multiplier - A multiplier which is used to determine exponential time set to socket for every retry attempt.
```

For ex. If RetryPolicy is created with these values

```
Timeout - 3000 ms, Num of Retry Attempts - 2, Back Off Multiplier - 2.0
```

Retry Attempt 1:

```
 time = time + (time * Back Off Multiplier);
    time = 3000 + 6000 = 9000ms
    Socket Timeout = time;
    Request dispatched with Socket Timeout of 9 Secs
```

Retry Attempt 2:

```
time = time + (time * Back Off Multiplier);
time = 9000 + 18000 = 27000ms
Socket Timeout = time;
Request dispatched with Socket Timeout of 27 Secs
```

So at the end of Retry Attempt 2 if still Socket Timeout happens Volley would throw a TimeoutError in your UI Error response handler.

```
//Set a retry policy in case of SocketTimeout & ConnectionTimeout Exceptions. 
//Volley does retry for you if you have specified the policy.
jsonObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```